# Why does my regex not work in Java

Tags: java, regex

I have to match custom (German) address strings to get the street, housenumber, zipcode and city. I have a regex for it which works with [RegExr](http://regexr.com/) and [Java Visual Regex Tester](http://www.ocpsoft.org/tutorials/regular-expressions/java-visual-regex-tester/).

This is the regex (delivered but editable):

```
^([^0-9]+)([0-9]+.*?)?(?:\w)?([0-9]{5})(?:\w)?(.*)$
```

This is the string:

```
NEUE BÜHNE Senftenberg, Theaterpassage 1, 01968 Senftenberg
```

This is my code:

```
String regex = "^([^0-9]+)([0-9]+\\.*?)?(?:\\w)?([0-9]{5})(?:\\w)?(\\.*)$";
String address = "NEUE BÜHNE Senftenberg, Theaterpassage 1, 01968 Senftenberg";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
String[] addrFromRegex;

// gives an array (length 1) with [0] == address
addrFromRegex = address.split(regex);

// gives an array (length 1) with [0] == address
addrFromRegex = pattern.split(address);
```

As for split(), the problem may be the faulty escaping. But for pattern I thought I do not have to care about this. What am I doing wrong?

**Update:**

The , in the string is not always given. Other possible address strings are:

```
NEUE BÜHNE Senftenberg; Theaterpassage 1; 01968 Senftenberg
NEUE BÜHNE Senftenberg Theaterpassage 1 01968 Senftenberg
NEUE BÜHNE Senftenberg|Theaterpassage|1|01968|Senftenberg
NEUE BÜHNE Senftenberg|Theaterpassage_1_01968_Senftenberg
...
```

I get the addresses via XML and I do not have any influence on the data provided. By the way the address provided here is an example for a faulty one. I have to deal with those too.

Comment: You need to match, not split.

Comment: Why have you added \\ in front of the `.` in the Java version of your expression?

Comment: I also suspect the `(?:\w)?` was meant to match *non*word chars, so it must be `\W?`, right? Check [this Java demo](http://ideone.com/ZDljlb).

Comment: @AndyTurner c&p error corrected.

Comment: @khelwood If I leave them, I get an empty array

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I will. Currently I have to check your implementation because I get a Nullpointer with it.

Comment: Well, I see, you also have `_` as separators, not just non-word chars. Try `"^([^0-9]+?)\\s*([0-9]+)[\\W_]+([0-9]{5})\\s*(.*)$"` pattern ([demo](http://ideone.com/kyxCnq)). Note that with `matches`, you may remove the initial `^` and trailing `$` from the pattern.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you very much. Found the Nullpointer. Had nothing to do with your code. Your implementation did the trick. The regex is awesome. Much better then the provided. I will gladly accept your solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main point is that your pattern is meant to *match* the strings you have. So, instead of `split`, you need to use `Pattern#matches()` and collect the captured values into a list/array/etc.

The fixed regex is

```
"^([^0-9]+?)\\s*([0-9]+)[\\W_]+([0-9]{5})\\s*(.*)$"
```

[image]

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string   (not necessary in `matches()`)
  -`([^0-9]+?)` - Group 1: one or more chars other than digits but as few as possible
- `\\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `([0-9]+)` - Group 2 capturing 1+ digits
- `[\\W_]+` - 1 or more chars that are either non-word or `_`
- `([0-9]{5})` -  Group 3 capturing 5 digits
- `\\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(.*)`  - Group 4 capturing the rest of the *line*
- `$` - end of string (not necessary in `matches()`).

[Java demo](http://ideone.com/hfIcOQ):

```
List<String> lst = new ArrayList<>();
String s = "NEUE BÜHNE Senftenberg, Theaterpassage 1, 01968 Senftenberg";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([^0-9]+?)\\s*([0-9]+)[\\W_]+([0-9]{5})\\s*(.*)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
if (matcher.matches()){
    lst.add(matcher.group(1));
    lst.add(matcher.group(2));
    lst.add(matcher.group(3));
    lst.add(matcher.group(4));
} 
System.out.println(lst); // => [NEUE BÜHNE Senftenberg, Theaterpassage, 1, 01968, Senftenberg]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution. Do you have an idea why String#split() does not work?

For clarification: I marked this answer as accepted because Wiktor provided the solution already in the comments before anyone else.

Comment: If you want to use `split`, you need to write a pattern that will match any text that you do not want to keep.

Answer (score 1):

You can start with the following code:

```
String regex =
    "^([\\p{L}\\s]+)(?:[,\\s]+)([\\p{L}\\s]+[0-9]+)(?:[,\\s]+)([0-9]{5}[\\p{L}\\s]+)$";
String address = "NEUE BÜHNE Senftenberg, Theaterpassage 1, 01968 Senftenberg";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(address);
matcher.matches();
System.out.println(matcher.group(1) + ":" + matcher.group(2) + ":" + matcher.group(3));
```

Answer (score 0):

> **I think  you need to change your method with regex**, I think your porpose of this code is check if the address is matched, if true get this address.

**Spilt** :

```
String source = "foo,bar" ;

String[] result = source.split(","); // you will get {"foo","bar"}
```

If you want check regex you should use **matches** instead:

```
// check if the address is matched with your regex
boolean isMathed= address.matches(regex);

// if matched set result variable with address
addrFromRegex = (isMatched ? address : null);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but I cannot just split with ",". There are strings without a ",". I did not mention this in my question. Sorry for that.